# Windows 11 Search in Zip File not Working

Tags: windows-explorer, zip, windows-11

So background, on Windows 10 I used to be able to search the contents of a .zip file for all files with a given file extension, such as *.eps.  From there I could select the files that I wanted and copy them out to another directory.

This does NOT seem to be the case any more in Windows 11.  I have tried all the "fixes" that various websites/YouTube videos provide, none of which work (restarting indexing service, checking "include zip files", etc.).  Was this functionality removed, and if so is there any chance that it will be added back?

Comment: There have been no changes to this particular feature, if it's not working on Windows 11, then it's possible it was working due to third-party software that was installed.  The capability in question, is actually pretty basic, and is primarily limited to extracting compressed .zip files natively. If the feature was native, I am not saying it was or isn't, we would have absolutely NO IDEA if it will be added back.  *That portion of your question cannot be answered by this community.*

Comment: Make sure in detailed index setting that you have chosen Contents for ZIP files otherwise it will just search for filenames.